# PL/SQL : Filter IDs based on a condition by grouping Persons

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a table with columns as below. I want to fetch the APP_ID, if all Persons in that application have at least one 'True' indicator in the Active Ind column.

```
APP_ID Act_Ind Person_Id
1000    true    p11 
1000    true    p12
1000    false   p13
2000    false   a20
2000    true    a20
2000    true    a21
2000    true    a22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause.

```
select app_id
from tablename
group by app_id
having count(distinct person_id)=count(distinct case when act_id='true' then person_id end)
```